# DevExpress WinForms Grid Initialization best practices

Tags: c#, .net, initialization, devexpress, xtragrid

I am using a DevExpress DataGrid control, and what I basically do on form initialization is: populate with data, set grouping, disabling some options via

```
gridView1.OptionsCustomization
gridView1.OptionsView
```

and doing things like:

```
gridView1.ExpandAllGroups();
```

Not the **question**: what to use to minimize the impact on first showing the XtraGrid? Data is not really big, maybe 20-30 rows at a time, not more. If looking for methods like SuspendLayout / ResumeLayout and such.

I know that there are methods like BeginUpdate and EndUpdate, but the invalidate the whole control, right? This is why I'm asking for "best practices". What are my options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such code should be implemented within the gridView's BeginUpdate / EndUpdate brackets.  For more information, please refer to the [Batch Modifications Overview](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument773) topic.